# Google calender repeating events

Tags: google-calendar-api

Google Calendar provides a simple way to add event this with HTML snippets:

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Brunch+at+Java+Cafe&dates=20060415T180000Z/20060415T190000Z&location=Java+Cafe,+San+Francisco,+CA&details=Try+our+Saturday+brunch+special:%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EFrench+toast+with+fresh+fruit%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3EYum!&trp;=true&sprop;=+website:http://www.javacafebrunches.com&sprop;=name:Jave+Cafe&gsessionid=OK&sf=true&output=xml

Is there any method where i can specify events as repeating and give the repeating dates?